# How to add additional line labels/group labels to a chart with ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, label

I have created a chart based on a group then changing the colours of the points on a subgroup.

How would I go about labeling these lines?

I have create a some sample data and code. I have a lot more data points and few more lines.

The lines are based on Day and the sub group is based on fuel. As you can see in the legend. I can only tell which is fuel not which line is Day 1 or 2.

```
Price <- seq(1, 20, by=1)
MW <- seq(1, 200, by=10)
fuel <- rep(c("Coal", "Gas", "Hydro", "Other"), each=5)
Day <- rep(1, each=20)
df1 <- data.frame(Price, MW,fuel, Day)

Price<-seq(0, 19, by=1)
MW <- seq(1, 100, by=5)
Day <- rep(2, each=20)
df2 <- data.frame(Price, MW, fuel, Day)

df <- rbind(df1, df2)
df <- df[with(df, order(Day, Price, fuel)), ]

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x=MW, y=Price, group=Day))+
    geom_line(aes(colour=fuel))+
    geom_point(aes(colour=fuel))
```

giving

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One *really* quick way to do it would be to use different shapes for the points:

```
gg <- ggplot(df, aes(x=MW, y=Price, group=Day))
gg <- gg + geom_line(aes(colour=fuel))+
gg <- gg + geom_point(aes(colour=fuel, shape=Day))
gg
```

[image: plot]

Otherwise, you could resort to adding a `geom_text()` layer with labels.